# The correlation coefficient captures only strength linear dependence, due to the normalised covariance, what does that mean?

Tags: correlation, linear

I understand that correlation coefficient can only capture the linear dependence.
I have just read a book saying that:

> “As a normalized covariance, the correlation coefficient captures only one particular aspect of dependence: The strength of linear dependence between the underlying random variables.”

I really do not understand: Why does normalized covariance lead the correlation coefficient to only captures the linear dependency structures? So, is that mean, without normalization, we can measure non-linear dependency?!

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you for comment. My question is why (because the normalized covariance) the correlation coefficient captures only one linear dependence.

Comment: Mary, my answer in the linked thread perhaps answers it (see e.g. the very last point): normalizarion of variances to unit makes two variances equal, and under this condition cov (now it is corr) will be maximal when (for centered variables) $X_i=Y_i$ (linearity), so we might say that corr measures how much close the values of the two variables to this relation.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the correlation coefficient is a normalized covariance. Because $Corr(X,Y) = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{V(X)V(Y)}}$.

As covariance mesure the strength of linear dependence between the underlying random variables, it is the same for the correlation coefficient which is just a normalization of covariance.

Comment: It is not true that `covariance measure the strength of [specifically] linear dependence`. Correlation - is true, and this is _because_ it is normalized.

Comment: Correlation and covariance measure exactly the same thing. The only difference between them is that correlation is normalized then vary between -1 and 1. After that, Covariance is influenced by the unit and the magnitude of the variables X and Y and it is not the cas of Correlation.

Comment: This is your stance, ok. But you may want to read my answer in the link provided to the question

Comment: Covariance measure _covariation_ which depends _both_ on linearity strength and on variances. Therefore I wouldn't rush to say covariance and correlstion coefficients "measure exactly the same thing". Which "exactly the same thing" then - one should clarify/define.